# How many college level varsity women's rugby teams are there in the US currently?

Tags: collegiate, rugby-union

I know there are a lot of club women's rugby teams in the US at the college level but I'm very curious how many of those teams are actually considered varsity level sports at their universities currently?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Harvard. Brown. Dartmouth. Quinnipiac. West Chester. Army. Lindenwood. Bowdoin. Eastern Illinios. Central Washington. Colorado Tech. Norwich. New England College. Life. Davenport. Sacred Heart. *Penn State. *Notre Dame College.

Comment: Hi welcome to the community and glad you could join us.  Its always useful to provide your source as a link if possible when answering a question.